# What's going on with Kohana Framework?

Tags: php, frameworks, kohana

Is Kohana framework alive or not?

[Development site](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/) returns an error when I try to enter it. I can't seem to find Kohana in more or less modern PHP frameworks comparison tables (like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#PHP) Wikipedia article)

I would consider it dead, but there seem to be some life signs in [Github](https://github.com/kohana/core) repo.

Than again, looking at their repo creates more questions than answers. [Official site](https://kohanaframework.org/index) states that last stable version is 3.3.3.1, but [last commit to 3.4](https://github.com/kohana/core/pull/578) happened at January and [last commit](https://github.com/kohana/core/tree/4.0/develop) to unstable 4.0 core happened two years ago.

Were there some official announcements or releases I've missed somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all intents and purposes it's dead. There's a very small community that still uses it and makes some commits to the repo, but the staff abandoned it a year ago.

The official announcement was in the forum, you can read it here - http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/12509/final-releases-of-kohana-beginning-of-ohanzee